# NetBeans forces me to save in specific encoding

Tags: character-encoding, netbeans-7

I am trying to save *.jspf file in UTF-8 using NetBeans. There is some cyrillic symbols eg. `Про проект` in file, so IDE warns me:

```
The header.jspf contains characters which will probably be damaged during
conversion to the ISO-8859-1 character set.
Do you want to save the file using this character set?
                                                               [Yes] [No]
```

When I press `[No]` button it cancels saving.
When I press `[Yes]` button it saves the file but the string looks like `ÐÑÐ¾ Ð¿ÑÐ¾ÐµÐºÑ` now.

In file properties encoding is set to `ISO-8859-1` and is grayed-out so i cant change it. Also project settings set to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the following line to the top of your *.jspf file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Encoding in your file properties will be changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To set the encoding on your JSP pages, add this lines to them.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why the Review posted it that way but it has been flagged for deletion and I voted to delete your answer, too, because you only blurted out code instead of giving an answer. Explain your answer and why you think it answers the question. That is what Stack Overflow is for, not a code writing service. Your question may be deleted soon by others for that reason. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It doesn't matter. You gave a poor answer and it will be deleted eventually.